# name 'mnist' not defined when trying to load a dataset

Tags: python, keras, installation

I'm trying to load the MNIST dataset from Keras, and after pip installing both Keras and TensorFlow I keep getting the error `name 'mnist' is not defined`.

I am working in the base anaconda environment and made sure I pip installed in the current environment. I'm not really sure where I went wrong. Below is the code I'm trying to run.

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

Comment: keras is a part of tensorflow now and doesn't require separate installation. Perhaps you installed old version of keras on top of existing tensorflow version, which messed it up?

Comment: I just realized that my title was incorrect, the error is "NameError: name 'mnist' is not defined". I got the same error when i just import tensorflow as tf and try to run tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

Comment: Can you import `keras`?

Comment: When I import keras I cant use any of the functions or attributes. I imported keras in once cell, and in the next i tried keras.__version__ and it said "name 'keras' is not defined"